# Can't compile from source files with Java 11 and JavaFX on Linux Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, java, compilation

I'm interested in compiling Java source repos that require JavaFX, but I keep running into issues. It appears my Java installation can't find the JavaFX files on my system.

I tried running [JavaFX Hello World](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) example to troubleshoot:

```
me@debian:~/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx$ export PATH_TO_FX=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib
me@debian:~/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx$ export PATH_TO_FX_MODS=/usr/share/openjfx/lib
me@debian:~/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx$ javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX -d mods/hellofx $(find src -name "*.java")
src/module-info.java:2: error: module not found: javafx.controls
    requires javafx.controls;
                   ^
1 error
me@debian:~/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx$
```

Package manager shows I have openjava-11-jdk and openjfx packages installed. All Java files are in their default install locations. I've tried compiling in Maven too. I run into similar issues that make it seem like Java can't find the JavaFX files.

How can I get this to work? Keep in mind I don't know a lot about Java. I'm not really trying to learn the language right now. I'm just trying to compile some stuff in Debian Linux. I would like to be able to compile Java source files in Bash, possibly with Maven. Thanks.

Comment: Your `PATH_TO_FX` is wrong, it should actually be the one you are using as the jmods path.

Comment: @JoséPereda I think this is on the right track, but it still isn't running. It doesn't hang or throw an error in Bash, but it just doesn't seem to run anything.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add "--add-modules javafx.controls" for javac. ("--add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH" for lazy ppls:)

```
$ echo $JAVAFX_HOME
/usr/local/java/javafx/14.0.0/javafx-sdk-14
$ javac --module-path $JAVAFX_HOME/lib --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java
$
```